# Understanding ICAP Server File Transfer In Java Problem

Tags: java, network-programming, icap

I am trying to get a Java ICAP server to interface with a blue coat device which is acting as the ICAP client.  The ICAP server I am working with is here:  [icap](https://github.com/jmimo/netty-icap).  Basically I have been getting things working and now I am stuck on why on the server side I am not receiving the file.  Below is a few lines of code that shows kind of where I am at most recently.  Obviously most of the code has been omitted.

```
IcapRequest request = (IcapRequest)e.getMessage();
ChannelBuffer buffer = null;
buffer = request.getHttpRequest().getContent();
if(buffer != null) {
    System.out.println("Buffer = " + buffer.toString(Charset.defaultCharset()));
}
try {    
    FileOutputStream fout= new FileOutputStream(testfile);
    while (request.getHttpResponse().getContent().readable()) {
        byte[] bb = new byte[request.getHttpResponse().getContent().readableBytes()];
        request.getHttpResponse().getContent().readBytes(bb);
        fout.write(bb);
}
```

Basically, I see using wireshark and on my server print statements I am getting the file name, the html request, etc.  But I am not getting all the content when it is a large file.  If it is a small .txt file I can get the content and save the txt file and all content to my server side disk.  If it is any kind of .docx file that is maybe about 10K in size or larger there appears to be only one ICAP client packet with content using a PSH method but no other content so if I try to save the file to my server on disk I am not getting all the content so the file is basically corrupt.  So at this point I am not sure why I cannot get my ICAP server to save the .docx file sent from the blue coat device as I am more leaning toward the problem is on the server side.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.